# Is it possible to have a Naming strategy for App Service Methods with Asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I recently upgraded to ABP 4.10.1 and every method in AppServices were now suffixed by Async, I think it's great news for us backend developers but it's not so great for the frontend developers / external users of the API -> the Swagger documentation feels less easy to read :

- every Create became CreateAsync
- every Update became UpdateAsync
- ...

I think the "Async" is really not needed. Is there a way to act on the `CreateControllersForAppServices` to tell it to remove any trailing `Async` when creating the Web API methods while keeping the AppService naming for backend developers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use ActionName attribute if you are willing to add this to every method.

```
[ActionName("Create")]
public string CreateAsync()
{
   return "Hello from Create Method";
}
```